# How to simulate user input multiple times for gets

Tags: ruby, rspec

I based my UI on a console and `case/when`. I want to write some rspecs for the code. This is my piece of code:

```
case choice
when '1' #Create account
  puts 'Enter username:'
  username = gets.chomp
  puts 'Enter Password'
  password = gets.chomp
  #createAccount() returns 1 or -1 after checking the database for duplicates
  operation = System.createAccount(username, password) 
  if operation == -1
    puts 'Error!'
  else
    puts 'Success!'
  end
when '2' #login case
  #code omitted
end
```

I have to get past the `gets.chomp` operation. I found various suggestions like using `allow` method to get past it:

```
STDIN.stub(:gets).and_return('name')
STDIN.stub(:gets).and_return('password')
```

but that didn't help; running the rspec test doesn't allow the code to get past `username = gets.chomp`.

Do you have any suggestions how I should write the spec (I want to test if operation value is 1) so that it passes `name` and afterwards `password`?

Comment: Ruby strongly encourages the `snake_case` naming convention for variables and method names, that is `create_account` instead of `createAccount`. The reason for this is Ruby is case-sensitive, capital letters indicate costants like `ClassName` or `CONSTANT`.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that returning error codes like `-1` is very C and not very Ruby. You probably want to return either an object, such as the account created, or throw an exception. This helps simplify flow-control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `gets` is a method defined in `Kernel` module, which is included (mixed in) your class, so you could mock it like this:

```
describe do 
  subject { described_class.new }
  before do 
    allow(subject).to receive(:gets).and_return('name', 'password')
    # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-6/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls 
  end

  specify do
    expect(System).to receive(:createAccount).with('name', 'password')
    subject.method_that_does_the_job
  end
end
```

(I assumed your `case choice...` code is inside `method_that_does_the_job`)

Some regard mocking tested object as a code smell (though I couldn't find any links that describe that, I'm sure I've read it somewhere).